# Echo a text line-by-line every 3 seconds in cli

Tags: cygwin, mingw

How would you output a new line of text from a text file every 3 seconds?

I've found that you can repeat a command with `forever` or `repeat`, as well as reading a file text line by line with, say, `sed`.

I know this can be done in a few lines of `perl` or `python`, I'm just curious at this point.

And what if the file is huge (so it shouldn't be buffered in ram)?

In my particular case, the output will be piped to `netcat`.

Comment: if possible, using tools available on `cygwin` and/or `mingw32`. I've found `lolcat`

Comment: Please remember the importance of adding `tags`, a `bash` tag in question and asking in `cygwin` and/or `mingw32` is contradictory

Comment: true, I actually meant cli, not bash :(

Comment: Remove the `bash` tag and add your appropriate tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{print $0 ;system("sleep 3")}' inputfile
```

Not sure of its efficiency. Just another way of doing it.

Comment: Using awk doesn't make sense here imo. But yes, probably not worth a downvote.

Comment: That works for me. However, it ain't evident to stop it, the `SIGINT` has to be captured by `awk`, not `system`.

Comment: The solution works perfect for me ;) thumbs up. I'll set it as an answer if there are no other candidates soon.